# Run scripts from a main script using the same subshell, does this happen to me?

Tags: bash

What is done within a script so that all scripts are automatically executed

```
#! / data / data / com.termux / files / usr / bin / bash

echo "This is the main script and is intended to execute all three auxiliaries."

# Run aux1.sh
source aux1.sh

# Run aux2.sh
 source aux2.sh
```

Every time when I embed my script with shc this happened to me:

> `./Auto-Help1.0.sh: line 65: source: ./DataWeb.sh: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: Call the nested shell script from inside the containing shell script with `source /path/to/script` or  `/bin/bash /path/to/script`

Answer (score 0):

`shc` replaces the shell script (which is normally a text file) by a binary executable (which is no longer a shell script).

`source` or `.` do assume that their argument is a text file, not a binary. So you cannot use the output of `shc` with `source`.

Comment: Oh habrá alguna forma amigo

Answer (score 0):

For people that are less versed in unix/linux shells, error messages may be a bit cryptic. The long version of the error message is:

Somewhere in your scripts, `aux1.sh` or `aux2.sh`, or perhaps even in a script that i called from those scripts, a script called `Auto-Help1.0.sh` is executed. That script, `Auto-Help1.0.sh` has an error in it, and more specifically at line 65.

At line 65 in that script, you will most probably find `source ./DataWeb.sh`. That means: execute `./DataWeb.sh` in the current shell as a set of shell commands.

However, `./DataWeb.sh` is not recognized as a shell script. It is a binary file. Therefore, it cannot be executed as a script, and it cannot be sourced like this.

*So what next?*

-Look at `./DataWeb.sh`. Is it a binary, or should it be a shellscript (as the name suggests)? Then why is it seen as a binary? 
- How do you normally execute `./DataWeb.sh`?  Try to do it that way in line 65 of `Auto-Help1.0.sh`, instead of sourcing the file.